# GPS does not work using Google Offline Maps on Android

Tags: gps, google-maps, offline-map

I am using offline maps functionality for Google Maps (9.71.0) on Android 6.0.1, Sony Xperia Z3 Compact.

I downloaded the offline maps of the region of my current location. If I disable my data connection, as well as WiFi once I one google maps, it cannot find my current location via GPS (GPS is enabled).

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: My cases often caused issues(not joking on my Samsung).  Make sure everything is up to date.  Other then that it should work.

Comment: Settings > location services > mode > device only (use GPS to determine location) . Try that. This is the path on Oreo and may vary on yours but you can search for that

Comment: Thanks beeshymas. I couldn't find this setting on Android 6.0.1 though.

Comment: @beeshymas I think this is a perfect solution here (first thing that I thought about) so certainly would deserve turning your comment into a full-featured answer.